# Google Maps API MVC example clarification

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am looking at the Google Maps API MVC usage example. See https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/mvcfun?csw=1

In the first simple example, I am unable to understand the marker.bindTo() call. The bindTo() is actually a method of the MVC object (See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MVCObject). marker itself is not an MVC object but a property of an object that has a MVC object as its prototype. So how is this bindTo method associated as a property of marker?

May be something elementary that I am missing here!

Thanks for any explanation.

```
    /**
    * A distance widget that will display a circle that can be resized and will
    * provide the radius in km.
    *
    * @param {google.maps.Map} map The map on which to attach the distance widget.
    *
    * @constructor
    */
    function DistanceWidget(map) {
    this.set('map', map);
    this.set('position', map.getCenter());

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    draggable: true,
    title: 'Move me!'
    });

    // Bind the marker map property to the DistanceWidget map property
    marker.bindTo('map', this);

    // Bind the marker position property to the DistanceWidget position
    // property
    marker.bindTo('position', this);
    }
    DistanceWidget.prototype = new google.maps.MVCObject();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The description may be found at the [documentation of MVCObject](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MVCObject):

*The MVCObject constructor is guaranteed to be an empty function, and so you may inherit from MVCObject by simply writing MySubclass.prototype = new google.maps.MVCObject();*

This technique will also be used for a `google.maps.Marker`-instance.

The **constructor** of a `google.maps.Marker`-instance is the constructor of a `google.maps.MVCObject`-instance, so a Marker will have the methods of a MVCObject

So the instance of a `google.maps.Marker` basically is an MVCObject extended with properties/methods of the `google.maps.Marker`-prototype

Comment: Molle. I find your answer very logical and easy to understand. THe answer is accepted and upvoted. I need a little clarification though: "The constructor of a google.maps.Marker-instance is the constructor of a google.maps.MVCObject-instance" This is significant but not documented anywhere OR too basic that I did not understand it. What other Google Maps object instances have constructors of the MVCObject? I guess I can write JS to check but an explanation would be more meaningful. Thanks

Comment: I find your answer very logical and easy to understand. THe answer is accepted and upvoted. I need a little clarification though: "The constructor of a google.maps.Marker-instance is the constructor of a google.maps.MVCObject-instance" This is significant but not documented anywhere OR too basic that I did not understand it. What other Google Maps object instances have constructors of the MVCObject? I guess I can write JS to check but an explanation would be more meaningful. Thanks

Comment: It's documented (but with other words), see: [**google.maps.Marker**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) , there is a notice *This class extends MVCObject* . All `google.maps`-classes where you find this notice have this constructor(e.g. Map too)

Answer (score 0):

You are right `bindTo` is a MVC model object function. there is MVC model object is the object of map which is set from

```
DistanceWidget.prototype = new google.maps.MVCObject();
```

above line.

```
bindTo(key:string, target:MVCObject, targetKey?:string, noNotify?:boolean);
```

And as per documentation the second parameter of bondTo is a MVC object. and in the above first line of code there is pass the object of map by using the this keyword.

So `this` is the MVC object of map class which is called in the above line. you can see it in your code also.

```
marker.bindTo('map', this);
```

And `DistanceWidget` is a function which has the object of map class that why bondTo has the MVC Object which is correct.